# Format ansible output to csv

Tags: shell, ansible

i have an issue when filtering ansible playbook and export the output to a txt file.
Those are my two attributes that i want to sava in a file.

> TASK [list_quota : debug]
>   **************************************************************************************************************************** ok: [localhost] => {
>       "Quota": "(188, 192, 694272, 700416, 5860, 5880, 0)" }
>
> TASK [list_project : debug]
>   **************************************************************************************************************************** ok: [localhost] => {
>       "TENANT": "project_name" }

This is the code that writes attributes in a text file:

```
- name: Save remote port with date
  shell: echo "{{ Project, Quota }}" >> /tmp/$( date +'%Y-%m-%d')_output.csv<<EOT
```

This is what i got

> (u'project_name', u'(0, 40, 0, 40960, 0, 2048, 0)')

I want to get this output

> 'project_name',0, 40, 0, 40960, 0, 2048, 0

Comment: Use [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html).